# How to convert these OpenGL Shaders to OpenGL ES shaders for GLES3 for android NDK?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, shader, glsles, opengl-es-3.0

The following Shaders fail with a return of -1, when i try.

```
col_attr = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "v_col");
```

i tried different settings including
switching ,

```
gl_FragColor
```

to

```
outColor
```

and

```
#version 300 es
```

to

```
#version 150 core
```

and many more, before i realized i'm completely lost and there are so many variables i dont know. i just need these simple shaders converted to something that works with GLESv3 for Android NDK in C++. All the help is highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Original Vertex Shader

```
#version 150 core
in vec3 v_pos;
in vec4 v_col;
out vec4 color;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
void main(){
        color = v_col;                    
        gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
}
```

Original Fragment Shader

```
#version 150 core
in vec4 color;
void main(){
            gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Update: Found that only the Fragment Shader fails at compilation.

New Vertex Shader - Compiles!

```
return "#version 300 es                 \n"
       "in vec3 v_pos;                 \n"
       "in vec4 v_col;                 \n"
       "out vec4 color;                \n"
       "uniform mat4 projection;        \n"
       "uniform mat4 view;            \n"
       "void main()                    \n"
       "{                              \n"
       "   color = v_col;                \n"
       "   gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);   \n"
       "}                              \n";
```

New Fragment Shader - Doesn't Compile!

```
return "#version 300 es                 \n"
       "in vec4 color;                  \n"
       "out vec4 outColor;              \n"
       "void main()                     \n"
       "{                               \n"
       "   outColor = color;            \n"
       "}                               \n";
```

New Fragment Shader - Compiles!

```
return "#version 300 es                 \n"
        "precision mediump float;       \n"
       "in vec4 color;                  \n"
       "out vec4 outColor;              \n"
       "void main()                     \n"
       "{                               \n"
       "   outColor = color;            \n"
       "}                               \n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to declare the [fragment shader output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Outputs) variable `out vec4 outColor`.
Further you've to add a [precision qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Precision_qualifiers):

A valid GLSL ES 3.00 fragment shader would be:

```c
#version 300 es

precision mediump float; 

in vec4 color;
out vec4 outColor;

void main(){
    outColor = color;
}
```

The version information (`#version 300 es`) has to be changed in the vertex shader, too.

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification - 4.3.6 Output Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) page 42:

> Fragment outputs are declared as in the following examples:
>
> ```
> out vec4 FragmentColor;
> out uint Luminosity;
> ```

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification - 4.5.4 Default Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) page 56:

> The fragment language has no default precision qualifier for floating point types. Hence for `float`, floating point vector and matrix variable declarations, either the declaration must include a precision qualifier or the default float precision must have been previously declared.

Comment: I updated the shaders. only Vertex shader compiles now. This is your original shader you gave me like 2 months ago . Thanx always. :D

Comment: the error was missing precision qualifier. Thanx a million.!

Comment: maybe you know how to help me solve my new problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54967251/10591628