# How can I integrate OpenCV 4.0 into a pure C++ Android NDK project?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

What are the steps necessary for me to integrate,

[the latest version of OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)

into a pure C++(No Java Code) Android NDK project, such as Android NDK Google tutorial:

[Endless-Tunnel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/endless-tunnel)
?

[official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) for android integration refers to much older version :OpenCV-2.4 and folder structures are no longer the same.

I am using Android Studio on Linux.

All help is highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Download opencv Android package (e.g. [opencv-4.0.1-android-sdk](https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/4.0.1/opencv-4.0.1-android-sdk.zip)) and unpack to, say, `~/android`.
2. To the bottom of [**CMakeLists.txt**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/endless-tunnel/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt), add

   ```
   set( OpenCV_DIR "~/android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni" )
   find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
   target_link_libraries(game opencv_java)
   ```

The package will define the following variables:

**OpenCV_LIBS                     :** The list of all imported targets for OpenCV modules.

**OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS             :** The list of OpenCV include directories. With CMake >= 2.8.11 you don't even need to write

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

This version of prebuilt OpenCV SDK defines also

**OpenCV_VERSION                  :** The version of this OpenCV build: **"4.0.1"**

**OpenCV_ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL :** Minimum required level of Android API: **"16"**.

This means that your app manifest needs **minSdkVersion** 16 or higher (the original sample needs a fix [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/endless-tunnel/app/build.gradle#L24)).

Instead of the shared library that contains all OpenCV functionality, you can use static libraries (**opencv_imgcodecs**, **opencv_stitching**, *et al*). These static libraries assume the default **ANDROID_STL=c++_static**.

For best results, use NDK **r.18** or **r.19**.

*UPDATE:* NDK **r.21** works well for opencv **4.3.0**.

Comment: With the recent improvements in both NDK and OpenCV, the older tricky ways (cf. *[Adding OpenCV to Native C code through CMake on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886764/192373)*) are no longer necessary.

Comment: Looks like the perfect answer. but i need like 3 days to confirm. thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexCohen now it compiles with a sample opencv code but when running i get ->  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load native library "/data/app/com.google.sample.tunnel-4TMDUdEDiQKyO7Y9pTu-cg==/lib/arm64/libgame.so": dlopen failed: library "libopencv_java4.so" not found

Comment: i have not used Cmake at this extent before. so i think i may have not included add_library linking to libopencv_java4.so, maybe?

Comment: If you are more comfortable with **Android.mk**, the OpenCV Android SDK includes **OpenCV.mk**. There, you need an extra `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on` to have the shared library included in the APK for you.

Comment: by prefernece i would like to try to make it with Cmake, because many libraries that my app will depend on uses makefiles. plus i understand that i need to learn more about cmake.

Comment: This looks to me as a glitch in Android Gradle plugin. I must experiment a bit more. The easy workaround is to add `<opencv>/sdk/native/libs` to **jniLIbs.src**

Comment: Manually created the jniLibs folder and copied the ~/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs content to that folder. [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg24S-Y8NU8  
Thank you @AlexCohn. if you find a solution after you experiment , please let me know.

Comment: After some experiments: I believe that the easiest solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/39205396/192373.

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn

Comment: The custom copy command is no longer necessary for imported targets when using the Android Gradle Plugin 4.0, see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs

Comment: I was always having a hard time building the whole project with `ccmake`. I should have seen this earlier thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to create shared objects`(.so)` and compile without using Android studio, here is my [blog](https://mdeore.medium.com/latest-android-ndk-to-build-opencv-ccecd11efa82). This is often useful when you would like to create a native third-party library.